# How to dynamically set the path of a link based on two different inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, variables

I have a model `Movie` and I have a page for comparing two movies. I use params `A` and `B` to set the two movies:

```
<%
  @movie1 = Movie.find_by(title: params[:A])
  @movie2 = Movie.find_by(title: params[:B])
%>
```

The left side of the page shows the "A" movie and the right side shows the "B" movie.

There's an option to remove the two current movies and input new ones. Right now the system I have is this: the "A" and "B" sides of the page both have a drop-down menu with clickable suggestions that come up as the user types, and clicking on a suggestion on the A side links to the same page except with `params[:A]` replaced, and vice versa.

For example, clicking on "Harry Potter" under the A side would use this link: `<%= link_to "Harry Potter", compare_path(A: "Harry Potter", B: params[:B]) %>`

But this way, the user has to wait for the page to load after selecting each movie. I want the user to be able to input both movies, and then press a button to reload the page with the new parameters.

So I would need some kind of "Run Comparison" link button, and clicking on a suggestion would have to reset that link's path, probably using jQuery. The trick is, the "A" suggestions would have to take into account the most recent "B" suggestion, and vice versa.

For example, if both selections are empty, and I select "Harry Potter" on the A side, then the link's path would be `compare_path(a: "Harry Potter", b: "")`, but then if I select "The Ring" on the B side, then the new path should be `compare_path(a: "Harry Potter", b: "The Ring")`. And then if I change my mind and select "Bewitched" on the A side, then the path is re-updated to `compare_path(a: "Bewitched", b: "The Ring")`

I'm completely lost. Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following route to parameterize `movie_a` and `movie_b` (Supposing you have a `MoviesController`):

```
get "compare/:movie_a/:movie_b" => "movies#compare", as: :compare
```

Note that `params[:movie_a]` and `params[:movie_b]` would map to the respective `:movie_a`, and `:movie_b` slug of the url.

Comment: So how would I dynamically set the proper path using the A and B dropdown lists?

Comment: Use `compare_path(movie_a: "movie_a_name", movie_b: "movie_b_name")`. If you're in javascript, use "/compare/movie_a_name/movie_b_name".

Comment: But if I update the path using the A side, how would I make the B params remain the same?

Comment: How are you updating it? Can't you use a variable as a placeholder for the params?

Comment: I was planning to use jquery to fill in a button when an item is clicked, so clicking on an A item would fire off something like this: `$("#run-comparison").html("<%=link_to "Run Comparison", compare_path(a: [name of item], b: [current value of b])%>");`, but I can't figure out how I could populate either variable.